# JQuery sortable and resizable with 3 columns. Making div larger affects the whole row below

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-resizable

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltc246wx/35/

```
<div id="sortable">
  <div class="widget">
    ggg
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    pppp
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
   ttt
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    yyyy
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    sds
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    sdfsg
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    vbbbbb
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    mmmm
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    nnn
  </div>
    <div class="widget">
    zzzz
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.widget{
  background-color: red;
    margin: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;  
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    /*float:left;*/
}

#sortable{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    });

    $(function() {
        $('.widget').resizable();
    });
});
```

I've been trying for a couple of hours and I can't get my head around how to make the behaviour I want.

If I resize the "mmmm" div to get more height the whole row below gets pushed down. I want the "mmmm" div to get more height and the "zzzz" div to stay in its position. Notice that the jquery sortable works how I want, but not the resize.

Im getting close if I use float:left instead of display: inline-block; and vertical-align: top;. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltc246wx/36/.

But still, all the div's to the right will still affect the whole row below when resize. Using float:right on every div to the right till fix this behavior but it will make the Jquery sortable not working on that div.

Any suggestions? I hope I'm being clear enough how I want it to work.

Comment: think you would need to use a masonry plugin to get the behaviour you want - maybe bind it to the resize end event

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try when I have time and report back how it went.

Answer (score 0):

The reason rows are being pushed down when resizing is because of html element flow.

Basically, you want to give the "portlets" absolute positioning, this way when you resize one widget contained by a portlet, the other portlets won't be pushed out of the way. You also need to detect collision between the portlets so that the widgets will not overlap.

Check out this codepen I made: https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/XwVzoQ

```
    // CREATE ZONE-COLS 
    function createCols() {
        $('.zone-inner').each(function(e) {
          var self = this;

          // get the zones width, divide by 12 to make 12 'columns'
          var zoneWidth = parseFloat(( $(self).width() ));
          var cols = Math.floor( (zoneWidth / 12) ); // make 12 columns
          var colP = ( (cols / zoneWidth) * 100 ); // one column percent of zone-inner
          var cols2 = Math.floor( cols * 2 ); // two columns
          var col2P = (colP) * 2; // two column percent of zone-inner
          var cols3 = Math.floor( cols * 4 ); // make 3 columns
          var col3P = (colP) * 4; // 3 columns percent of zone-inner

          var zoneHeight = ($(self).height()); 
          var rows = Math.floor( zoneHeight / cols3); 
          var colAmount = Math.floor( 5 );
          for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
              for (var y = 0; y < colAmount; y++) {
                  $(self).append('<div class="zone-col absolute" style="min-width: '+ (col2P) +'%; min-height: '+ cols3 +'px; top:'+ (cols3 * x) +'px; left: '+ (cols2 * y) +'px; "></div>');
              }
          }
        });
    } createCols();
```

Here I am just creating the  portlets, named "zone-cols" in my code, and placing them in the desired positions, I want 5 portlets spread across, the sixth would cause overflow in my code because my widgets will be 1/3 the zone's width, (3 columns);

**Some "issues" with this:**

- This isn't an issue for me but it might be one for you: This will take away the "*sortable*" functionality, as in you won't be able to drag a widget over another and have them swap places, so you would need to do some more work with that.
- Once there is no resize collision and the user wants to resize further, they must stop resizing and start again. I am able to keep the resize going once there is no collision, but it will only affect the last widget, possibly something wrong with my `.each()` loop, but I just cannot figure out what the problem may be.
- Resizing will not push ANY widgets down, it's not needed in my project so that is some more code you would need to add.